# How do I select booting from a USB Flash drive to reinstall Kubuntu?

Tags: boot, system-installation, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 18.04 installed on my PC, but it is corrupted, soI want to reinstall. I plugged my USB and tried that, but instead of booting into the installer app, it always runs the prior installation of Kubuntu from the internal drive instead.

When I turn on the PC, the bios says the normal stuff about booting, like "Run Kubuntu", "Recovery mode", "advanced" and these stuff. Last time when I tried to install Kubuntu I selected the "Run Kubuntu" button, so this time around I'm selecting the same button but it doesn't load up the installation screen.

I can provide more info when needed.

Comment: have you set the USB drive as the default boot device in your bois settings?

Comment: It's at the top of the list but Idk if it's the default device

Comment: There are a few things to try. One is to [verify that your ISO download isn't corrupted using GPG](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0). Another is to try a new USB drive in case yours is bad. Another is to burn a DVD instead of a USB drive and borrow someone's portable USB DVD drive or, if you have a desktop, someone's internal DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your PC, before it gets to where it asks for "Run Kubuntu" vs  "Recovery mode" vs "advanced", et al., that you need to boot from the USB Flash drive. When it gets to those prompts, it has already decided you have not told it to boot from your USB flash drive, so you need to get in there quicker.

You have not told us what kind of machine you have, and different manufacturers have different keystrokes to select booting from something other than the internat drive. For example, with Lenovo laptops, you press the blue button to redirect away from the internal drive. Some machines use <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, or <kbd>F12</kbd>. Look up the instructions from the PC manufacturer to find what the have programmed into the BIOS, and use that to redirect booting to the USB flash drive.

Comment: I pressed F12 then booted into the USB drive but the same problem happened, it didnt load up the installation session

Comment: I plugged out the usb mouse in case it was hindering the stuff but same problem so I really don't know.

Comment: OK, how about telling us who made your PC, and what's the engineering model number from the serial number plate? The 'marketing' model number on the front or top generally covers many different true models, which is why I ask for the model number from the serial number plate. Once you have it, please click on the `edit` link which goes to https://askubuntu.com/posts/1063613/edit and add that information to the original question.

Comment: Other keys to try are `F1`, `F2`, and `Esc`. Also, in the answer above, to format a key to press so that it looks like a keyboard key, surround it with `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`.

Comment: TY, CTR, for the tip.