# How to factory reset Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu

How can I factory reset my Kubuntu and return it to new-like state, without reinstalling it?
(I am having problems reinstalling the OS.)

Comment: Why do you want to reset? Even if somehow "resetting without reinstalling" be possible, troubleshooting your problem will definitely be easier.

Comment: You already asked for help with this at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063613/how-do-i-select-booting-from-a-usb-flash-drive-to-reinstall-kubuntu

Comment: That's a completely different topic lol

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, reinstalling is the way to go. There's no easy way to back out every single change that's been made to the system. Reinstalling takes not too much time, is fairly easy, and gets the job done.

One possible alternative is backing up your hard drive right after installing and then restoring from that backup, but it's rare for a person to do that because installing from scratch allows you to do things like install a newer version of Ubuntu to save time on update downloads and it avoids problems like the backup getting corrupted.

I'd recommend asking a new question here dealing with the issues you're experiencing with the install.